# Создание\удаление объектов. Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. 
Пишу простую 2д игру на юнити. Суть в том, что шарик прыгает, а платформа под ним движется. Нужно в процессе игры генерировать новые платформы. Тут возникла проблемка с использованием метода *Instantiate*. Ссылки на префаб платформы хранятся в массиве *platforms*. Их я присвоил через редактор Unity. После удаления старого объекта вылезает исключение, но почему? Ссылка ведь на префаб, а не на конкретный объект на сцене.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Generate : MonoBehaviour {
    GameObject emptyObject;
    public GameObject[] platforms = new GameObject[3];
    void Start(){
        Data.pointOfGenerate.Set(9.1f, -4.5f, 0.0f);
        emptyObject = GameObject.Find("EmptyObject");
    }
    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D checkObj)
    {
        if (checkObj.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
        {
            GenerateNewPlatform();
        }
    }
    void GenerateNewPlatform() {
        Data.nextPlatform = platforms[Random.Range(0,3)];
        Instantiate(Data.nextPlatform, Data.pointOfGenerate, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Ошибка

Comment: Какой эксепшен вылетает и покажите метод удаления платформы.  
Советую посмотреть в сторону ObjectPool'ов.

Comment: @ВладЛеонидов, пуллинг не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу, так что лучше не добавлять его в данный вопрос.

Comment: подозреваю, что у вас проблема в Data.pointOfGenerate - это точка спауна null, а не префаб. Какой текст ошибки то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. В редакторе Unity я прикрепил к скрипту Generate объект со сцены, думая что это префаб (у них были одинаковые имена). Поэтому при удалении платформы со сцены функция Instantiate ссылалась на несуществующий объект.
[image: Редактор Unity]